# How to update a package's dependency in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, socks

I can see that npm indicated that there is severe security vulnerability in my application. I tried to use `npm audit fix` but the issue persisted, I tried `npm update` to update the packages but the issue persisted.

I checked and I saw that the issue is coming from `socks` package which depends on another package that actually has the issue. When I checked `socks` package, I can see that they have a new update which is version `2.7.3` while the one on my `node_module` is version `2.7.1`. I checked the `package-lock.json` file and searched for `socks` and I can see that `mongodb` is using socks version `2.7.1`

My `package-lock.json` file for `socks` looks like this:

```json
     "node_modules/npm/node_modules/socks": {
      "version": "2.7.1",
      "inBundle": true,
      "license": "MIT",
      "dependencies": {
        "ip": "^2.0.0",
        "smart-buffer": "^4.2.0"
      },
```

I would like to update this particular module to the latest version to see if that fixes the issue. I can also see that `socks-proxy-agent` is using older version of `socks`:

```json
    "node_modules/npm/node_modules/socks-proxy-agent": {
      "version": "7.0.0",
      "inBundle": true,
      "license": "MIT",
      "dependencies": {
        "agent-base": "^6.0.2",
        "debug": "^4.3.3",
        "socks": "^2.6.2"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">= 10"
      }
    },
```

And `mongodb` has these dependencies:

```json
      "integrity": "sha512-NBGA8AfJxGPeB12F73xXwozt8ZpeIPmCUeWRwl9xejozTXFes/3zaep9zhzs1B/nKKsw4P3I4iPfXl3K7s6g+Q==",
      "dependencies": {
        "bson": "^5.5.0",
        "mongodb-connection-string-url": "^2.6.0",
        "socks": "^2.7.1"
      },
```

What is the best way to resolve this issue? I have deleted my `package-lock.json` file and `node_module/` directory and did `npm install`, same issue persists. They are still using the older version of socks and socks it self has not updated on my application. I also did `npm ls socks` to see packages using `socks` and I saw:

```
├─┬ mongoose@7.6.8
│ └─┬ mongodb@5.9.1
│   └── socks@2.7.3
└─┬ npm@9.9.2
  └─┬ make-fetch-happen@11.1.1
    └─┬ socks-proxy-agent@7.0.0
      └── socks@2.7.1
```

After running `npm audit fix`, I still get same security vulnerability alert:

```
ip  *
Severity: high
NPM IP package vulnerable to Server-Side Request Forgery (SSRF) attacks - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-78xj-cgh5-2h22
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install socks@2.7.3, which is outside the stated dependency range
node_modules/ip
  socks  1.0.0 - 2.7.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of ip
  node_modules/socks

2 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix
```

I believe that the new update has the fix because the package that is causing the problem in `socks` package has a new update in `socks` package latest version.

Comment: npm audit fix was the first thing I did but I continue to get the alert. I have updated the question with a screenshot of the error I get from NPM.

Comment: I just updated the screenshot. This is just an alert from NPM whenever I do NPM install or NPM update. I have provided codes indicating the package trees that are affected.

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of my package.json file. I have no special configuration there.

Comment: Fixing the output of `npm ls`, it becomes clearer that the issue is `npm@9.9.2` -> `make-fetch-happen@11.1.1` -> `socks-proxy-agent@7.0.0` -> `socks@2.7.1` (also clued in the path `node_modules/npm/node_modules/socks`), because `npm` uses [`bundleDependencies`](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/8d9d7351f5f9cfd7028a9f47cde520ca393218dd/package.json#L125-L196) to vendor everything. But that leaves the question: why _is_ npm 9 a production dependency? Typically that's part of the runtime environment, rather than a dependency.

Comment: How do I go about fixing this issue? Do I need to uninstall NPM?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thank you for pointing out what caused my problem. I have fixed the issue now after removing npm from my production dependcies